# vbscript test ftp connection

Tags: testing, vbscript, ftp, connection

I am try to test my ftp connection,

I need to recover the time it takes to make the connection and go in a directory

and I must have an error message when the user or the password is wrong

I try this but I can't get an error when the connection is not established or the user or the password is wrong.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" )       

        wshShell.run "ftp.exe",true  
        wscript.sleep 100
        date_before_timestamp=Timer

        WshShell.SendKeys "ftp.exe"&chr(13)
        WshShell.SendKeys "open 127.0.0.1 21"&chr(13)
        WshShell.SendKeys "galene"&chr(13)
        WshShell.SendKeys "galene"&chr(13)
        WshShell.SendKeys "cd test"&chr(13)
        WshShell.SendKeys "quit"&chr(13)
        WshShell.SendKeys chr(13)
        date_after_timestamp=Timer

        interval= date_after_timestamp - date_before_timestamp
        wscript.echo interval
```

how i can make ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Add your FTP commands to a text file and pass it as an argument (using the `-s` switch). Then, redirect the output of the FTP command to a file that you can parse.

```
' Create the FTP command file...
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("c:\ftp.txt", True)
    .WriteLine "USER testuser"  ' Login
    .WriteLine "secret1"        ' Password
    .WriteLine "cd test"        ' Perform a command once logged in
    .WriteLine "quit"           ' Done
    .Close
End With

' Run the command and capture its output...
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    tmrStart = Timer
    .Run "%comspec% /c ftp -n -v -s:c:\ftp.txt ftp.mysite.com >c:\output.txt", 0, True
    tmrEnd = Timer
End With
```

Here's an example of what you might see in `output.txt` when the login fails:

```
ftp> USER testuser
User cannot log in.
```